# Logging to a single file from multiple processes using fork method

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm studying how to log to a single file from multiple processes and encountering some problems.

At first I wrote the following code without logging module:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from random import randint
from time import sleep
import multiprocessing


def get_utc_now() -> str:
    iso_8601_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'

    return datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime(iso_8601_format)


def child_process(index: int):
    waiting_time = randint(1, 5)
    print('{} Child No.{}: Waiting {}s.'.format(get_utc_now(), index, waiting_time))
    sleep(waiting_time)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    children = {}

    multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork')

    for i in range(1, 6):
        child = multiprocessing.Process(target=child_process, args=(i,))
        children[i] = child
        child.start()
        print('{} Parent: Forking Child No.{} whose pid is {}.'.format(get_utc_now(), i, child.pid))

    done_count = 0
    while done_count < len(children):
        for j, c in children.items():
            if c is not None and not c.is_alive():
                print('{} Parent: Child No.{} completed.'.format(get_utc_now(), j))
                children[j] = None
                done_count += 1

    print('{} Parent: All done.'.format(get_utc_now()))
```

The result is like:

```
2016-01-14T01:51:50+0000 Parent: Forking Child No.1 whose pid is 21.
2016-01-14T01:51:50+0000 Parent: Forking Child No.2 whose pid is 22.
2016-01-14T01:51:50+0000 Parent: Forking Child No.3 whose pid is 23.
2016-01-14T01:51:50+0000 Parent: Forking Child No.4 whose pid is 24.
2016-01-14T01:51:50+0000 Child No.2: Waiting 1s.
2016-01-14T01:51:50+0000 Child No.4: Waiting 3s.
2016-01-14T01:51:50+0000 Child No.5: Waiting 4s.
2016-01-14T01:51:50+0000 Child No.1: Waiting 5s.
2016-01-14T01:51:50+0000 Child No.3: Waiting 5s.
2016-01-14T01:51:50+0000 Parent: Forking Child No.5 whose pid is 25.
2016-01-14T01:51:51+0000 Parent: Child No.2 completed.
2016-01-14T01:51:53+0000 Parent: Child No.4 completed.
2016-01-14T01:51:54+0000 Parent: Child No.5 completed.
2016-01-14T01:51:55+0000 Parent: Child No.1 completed.
2016-01-14T01:51:55+0000 Parent: Child No.3 completed.
2016-01-14T01:51:55+0000 Parent: All done.
```

After reading [Logging to a single file from multiple processes](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes), I wrote the code with logging module:

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
import logging
import logging.handlers
import multiprocessing


def child_process(queue, index: int):
    child_handler = logging.handlers.QueueHandler(queue)
    child_logger = logging.getLogger('Child No.{}'.format(index))
    child_logger.addHandler(child_handler)
    child_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    waiting_time = randint(1, 5)
    child_logger.log(logging.INFO, 'Waiting {}s.'.format(waiting_time))
    sleep(waiting_time)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root_logger = logging.getLogger()
    root_handler = logging.FileHandler('test.log')
    root_formatter = logging.Formatter(
        '[%(levelname)s] %(asctime)s %(name)s: %(message)s',
        '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
    )
    root_handler.setFormatter(root_formatter)
    root_logger.addHandler(root_handler)

    children = {}

    multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork')
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()

    parent_handler = logging.handlers.QueueHandler(q)
    parent_logger = logging.getLogger('Parent')
    parent_logger.addHandler(parent_handler)
    parent_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    for i in range(1, 6):
        child = multiprocessing.Process(target=child_process, args=(q, i))
        children[i] = child
        child.start()
        parent_logger.log(logging.INFO, 'Forking Child No.{} whose pid is {}.'.format(i, child.pid))

    done_count = 0
    while done_count < len(children):
        for j, c in children.items():
            if c is not None and not c.is_alive():
                parent_logger.log(logging.INFO, 'Child No.{} completed.'.format(j))
                children[j] = None
                done_count += 1

    parent_logger.log(logging.INFO, 'All done.')
    q.put_nowait(None)
```

And the result is:

```
[INFO] 2016-01-14T01:57:06+0000 Parent: Forking Child No.1 whose pid is 40.
[INFO] 2016-01-14T01:57:06+0000 Parent: Forking Child No.2 whose pid is 43.
[INFO] 2016-01-14T01:57:06+0000 Child No.1: Waiting 1s.
[INFO] 2016-01-14T01:57:06+0000 Parent: Forking Child No.3 whose pid is 44.
[INFO] 2016-01-14T01:57:06+0000 Parent: Forking Child No.4 whose pid is 45.
[INFO] 2016-01-14T01:57:06+0000 Child No.2: Waiting 4s.
[INFO] 2016-01-14T01:57:06+0000 Child No.3: Waiting 3s.
[INFO] 2016-01-14T01:57:06+0000 Parent: Forking Child No.5 whose pid is 47.
[INFO] 2016-01-14T01:57:06+0000 Child No.4: Waiting 5s.
[INFO] 2016-01-14T01:57:06+0000 Child No.5: Waiting 2s.
[INFO] 2016-01-14T01:57:07+0000 Parent: Child No.1 completed.
[INFO] 2016-01-14T01:57:08+0000 Parent: Child No.5 completed.
[INFO] 2016-01-14T01:57:09+0000 Parent: Child No.3 completed.
[INFO] 2016-01-14T01:57:10+0000 Parent: Child No.2 completed.
[INFO] 2016-01-14T01:57:11+0000 Parent: Child No.4 completed.
[INFO] 2016-01-14T01:57:11+0000 Parent: All done.
```

The 2nd code works, but the pids of children are not consistent like the 1st one. It seems like my 2nd code forks other processes during loop, and I can not figure out how and why. How can I improve this code to solve this situation?

Comment: Running your second code, I get perfectly sequential PIDs, without gaps, as in your first example. Presumably, your OS just fired up a few processes in the mean time. At least, I assume this is what your question is about.

Comment: @Evert So it is just because my 2nd code runs slower than 1st one. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Probably. It will depend on your OS; make sure hardly anything else is running. E.g., a terminal only login might be good to test this.